# Why this shift operation plus bitwise works only up to 31?

Tags: c++, c, bit-shift

Why shift operation below works and end up equal?
Is there any name for this pattern?
I am trying to find out what was going on in the head of the person who wrote this code!

```
int i = 0x1;
i |= 0x1 << 1;
i |= 0x1 << 2;
i |= 0x1 << 3;
i |= 0x1 << 4;
i |= 0x1 << 5;

int j = 5;

if( ((0x1 << (j + 1)) - 1) == i)
{
    // WHY?
}
```

I tried to check if this is true for all numbers but only works up to 31.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    int total_1 = 0x1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        total_1 |= 0x1 << j;
    }

    int total_2 = (0x1 << (i + 1)) - 1;
    if (total_2 == total_1) {
    } else {
        cout << i << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Please explain the first part why they would end up equal?

Comment: Pop quiz: if you have only 32 bits in your `int`, what exactly do you expect to happen when you attempt to shift more bits than there could possibly be shifted?

Comment: In your own words, what do you think that operator actually does? If you don't understand it, did you try looking up documentation? Did you try putting `c shift operator` into a  search engine? Anything else? In your own words, what is *binary*, and how is it used to represent integer values? If you have an integer written in binary like `11111` what do you expect the next larger integer to look like? Why?

Comment: Shifting by the number of bits in the type or more has undefined behavior in both C and C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik — I expect the result to be zero, but some compilers don’t agree. <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any name for this pattern?

`0x1u << pos` (or just `1u << pos`) is a pattern for getting a number with only the bit in position `pos` is set. Using signed `0x1` is usually an anti-pattern.

`i |= 1u << pos` is a pattern for setting a bit in position `pos` of the integer `i`.

`(1u << pos) - 1` is a pattern for creating a pattern of set bits only in positions lesser than `pos`.

> Why shift operation below works and end up equal?

Perhaps it may help to look at intermediate results:

```
                     // least significant byte
int i = 0x1;         // 0b0000'0001
i |= 0x1 << 1;       // 0b0000'0011
i |= 0x1 << 2;       // 0b0000'0111
i |= 0x1 << 3;       // 0b0000'1111
i |= 0x1 << 4;       // 0b0001'1111
i |= 0x1 << 5;       // 0b0011'1111

int      j = 5;
 0x1 << (j + 1)
 0x1 <<    6         // 0b0100'0000
(0x1 << (j + 1)) - 1 
 0b0100'0000     - 1 // 0b0011'1111
```

> only works up to 31

`int` is probably 32 bits wide on your system. If you left shift a 32 bit 0x1 by 31 or greater, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. If you were to use `0x1u`, then you could shift by 31, but 32 and above would be UB.

Answer (score 3):

> UPDATE Please explain the first part why they would end up equal?

`((0x1 << (j + 1)) - 1)` sets `j` lower bits to `1`

Example:

If `j` is 3, `j+1` is 4, `1` shifted by 4 is `0b1000`; subtract 1 - you get `0b0111`

Re: `Is there any name for this pattern?`  - I looked [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html), this pattern is used a couple of times, but is not named. Probably, too obvious :)